# NUnit 3 ExpectedException with returned object

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

In Nunit2 i had a test like

```
[Test, ExpectedException(typeof(NullReferenceException))]
public void NullString()
{
    secToken = new SecurityToken(null);

    secToken.user.Should().BeNull();
    secToken.pass.Should().BeNull();
    secToken.ip.Should().BeNull();
}
```

How to rewrite it in Nunit3? I just can't handle it...

Comment: Could you try Assert.That(() => {your test}, Throws.TypeOf<NullReferenceException>());?

Comment: Yes, but i dont't have the returned object. I've tried that. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think to do this Assert.That(NullString, Throws.TypeOf<NullReferenceException>());? But to scope everything what is within the test into this anonymous method...

Answer (score 3):

Suggest using `Assert.Throws`, example:

```
Assert.Throws<NullReferenceException>(() => secToken = new SecurityToken(null))
```

It is a closer scoping of the lines under test rather than just saying 'I think something in the test will throw'.

It also allows you to continue with the lines below, and returns the exception that was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think the test is a bit unclear. Where do you expect the exception to occur? In the constructor? If it should be thrown there, why bother checking values on the constructed object?

Second, I would follow Lepijohnny's suggestion and follow the NUnit 3 style using the "[constraint model](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Constraint-Model)".

Something like:

```
[Test]
public void NullString()
{
    Assert.That(() => new SecurityToken(null), Throws.Exception.TypeOf<NullReferenceException>());
}
```

Comment: The "problem" with this approach is that it doesn't give you the returned exception, which I agree is not needed for the test above, but the OP has specifically asked for that.  Using `Assert.Throws` will provide both a semantically similar test, and also give the OP what he asked for

Comment: The constraint model method actually does allow you to write assertions on the returned exception. You don't get it back, true, but you can do e.g. `.And.Message.Contains`.

Comment: See e.g. [NUnit documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/ThrowsConstraint).